# php multi dimensional foreach loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array and I am trying to loop over it with foreach but I am getting the

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on the inner loop.

I am not sure what I have incorrect. I have tried with using `$key`

Here is the array:

```
array(3) { ["company_id"]=> string(3) "159" 
    [0]=> array(9) { 
        ["company_id"]=> string(3) "159" 
        ["employee_id"]=> string(3) "544" 
        ["pay_week1"]=> string(1) "0" } 
    [1]=> array(9) { 
        ["company_id"]=> string(3) "159" 
        ["employee_id"]=> string(3) "545"  } }
```

My loop:

```
foreach ($this->request->data['MonthlyReturn'] as $key=>$m) // Cycle through each record

{
    foreach ($key as $empl)

    {
        $employee = $empl['employee_id'];
        print '<pre>';
        print_r ($employee);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: You foreach the key of an array value. That is not going to work. Foreach the value ($m)

Comment: I get the same result with $m

Comment: @KeithPower : Check my answer I explained it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In inner foreach you are looping `$key` Change it to `$m`
2. Also your first value of the arrays is not a array ie `["company_id"]=> string(3) "159"` is a string (159) so it will give error. so before inner foreach check for array also `if(is_array($m)){`.

Here is the code :

```
         foreach ($this->request->data['MonthlyReturn'] as $key=>$m){
              if(is_array($m)){
                  echo $m['employee_id'];
              }
              else{
                   echo $m;
              }
         }
```

Comment: I like how you copied his horrible indentation

Comment: I am using cakephp so it is setting ["company_id"]=> string(3) if it is a string can I still get the values out?

Comment: Yes.. check my answer ... `else` condition of `is_array`

Comment: all I get each time is $m being echoed out. I have no control over the array is outputted, is there a way to still get the employee_id?

Comment: @KeithPower :  If you want only employee_id, you dont want the inner loop, see the edited answer

Comment: thanks for the help. I have a much understanding of looping over arrays

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
foreach ($key as $empl)  // $key is array key
```

to

```
foreach ($m as $empl)   // $m is your array value
```

Comment: I get the same result I am afraid

Comment: @KeithPower check prashant's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not going to work on that code. It expects a multidementional array but it isn't completely
There is a string value on the first depth

```
array(3) {
        ["company_id"]=> string(3) "159" <--- problem
        [0]=> array(9) { 
            ["company_id"]=> string(3) "159" 
            ["employee_id"]=> string(3) "544" 
            ["pay_week1"]=> string(1) "0" 
        } 
        [1]=> array(9) { 
            ["company_id"]=> string(3) "159" 
            ["employee_id"]=> string(3) "545"  
        } 
    }
```

It tries to loop through a string value, which is generating an error